# My CSS question was put on hold as off-topic. How can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question I asked about achieving a particular layout with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34364840/777586) was put on hold as off-topic, for seeking debugging help without adequately explaining the problem:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

I am confused by this because

- I am not seeking debugging help. The question is conceptual.
- I've described the layout I am trying to achieve, with both text and a picture.
- I've explained my attempts and their deficiencies.

What else can I do to improve the question?

Comment: I guess you can include the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Before I click the question let comment on a line here:

> I am not seeking debugging help. The question is conceptual.

That's the thing. Concepts are abstracts, and to achieve them you can use a thousand plus one ways. What you may think is only possible using one *true method* can be easily realized using other methods if people is creative enough (they are).

Now, you say "I've explained my attempts and their deficiencies.", well, where are these attempts? Why should we try to figure out what you have done, to try and guess what the crux of the problem is?

Remember, more is usually better, because if there's more than it's needed someone can remove it, but who can add what it lacks?